# Is there a way to replace the key fob (remote keyless entry transmitter) of a 2011 Hyundai Santa Fe's without spending a large amount of money?

Tags: hyundai, fob, santa-fe

[image]

Given that it's been around for 12 years, the unlock button on a 2011 Hyundai Santa Fe is frequently unresponsive. I've seen Chevy remote keys sold in automotive stores for a dollar amount in the teens. So I called my local AutoZone and asked how much it'd take to replace the key fob. They quoted me $219! And I have to take it to a dealer or locksmith. I think It's not worth it to spend that much on a key fob. Is there a way to make the unlock button more responsive or replace it without spending a large amount of money?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning it? Quite often the button (the actual button on the inside of the remote) becomes dirty and won't work all the time. Cleaning it with spray cleaner which will not leave a residue will often do the trick, like MAF cleaner.

Comment: Did you replace the battery?

Comment: Replacement remotes are relatively low cost. Unfortunately, Hyundai chose to use software requiring dealers, mobile techs, repair shops, locksmiths and diyers to have a dedicated scantool to access Hyundai electronics to program replacement remotes. Your options are; calling Hyundai dealers for costs (whether you bring remotes or not), call repair shops, call mobile techs or vehicle locksmiths for costs.

Comment: Have you tried opening it? If you have, can you show a photo of the buttons?